# Relationship (database first) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, relationship

I created a database, then applied dataase-first. Then it automatically imported the database to VS. Please tell me, when database-first automatically indicates relationship? Probably not, my data is not being imported. Could you tell me how to establish connections correctly? I read about the fluent api and about the fact that you can specify keys and properties directly in the table classes (And when is it better to do through fluent, and when to specify directly?)

My 1st table

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Web;

    [DataContract]
    public partial class customer
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public customer()
        {
            this.dishesrankings = new HashSet<dishesranking>();
            this.orders = new HashSet<order>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int Id_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int PhoneNum_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email_Cus { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<dishesranking> dishesrankings { get; set; }
        public virtual customerpreference customerpreference { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<order> orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My 2nd table

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Web;

    [DataContract]
    public partial class customerpreference
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Id_Res { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name_Dis { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Id_Type { get; set; }

        public virtual customer customer { get; set; }
        public virtual order order { get; set; }
        public virtual type_dishes type_dishes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MySQLEntities

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MySQLEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MySQLEntities()
            : base("name=MySQLEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<customer>()
        .HasMany(c => c.customerpreference)
        .WithOptional(o => o.Customer);
            //throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();//here problem
        }

        public virtual DbSet<customer> customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<customerpreference> customerpreferences { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<dish> dishes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<dishesranking> dishesrankings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ingridient> ingridients { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<order> orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<restaraunt> restaraunts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<type_dishes> type_dishes { get; set; }
        public object Parameters { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Here I create data(Id_Cus) but it doesn't import in 2nd table

```
 public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
        {
            //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities();
            customer cust = new customer();
            {
                cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
                cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
                cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
                cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
            };
            dc.customers.Add(cust);

            customerpreference custPref = new customerpreference()
            {
                Id_Cus = customerDataContract.Id_Cus,
                Id_Res = 0, // some value
                Name_Dis = null, // some value
                Id_Type = 0 // some value
            };
            dc.customerpreferences.Add(custPref);

            dc.SaveChanges();

            int k = Convert.ToInt32(cust.Id_Cus);
            customer custFromDb =(from n in dc.customers
                                  where n.Id_Cus == k
                                  select n).Include(c => c.customerpreference).First();


        }
```

perhaps problem in

```
 cust = (from n in dc.customers
                    where n.Id_Cus == k
                    select n).Include(c =>c.customerpreference).ToList().First();
            dc.customers.Add(cust);
            dc.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does automatically model foreign keys. You can see that it has done so in your model because there are navigation properties such as dishesrankings in your Customer class.

We had a database first project. We would update it by changing the database using dbup and then updating the model from the database. This way you ensure consistency between the model and the database.

DbUp: https://dbup.github.io/

DbUp is a tool to run scripts to make changes to the database that allows versioning and rollback and it is very useful if you're using database first.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Then I have a question. I will now attach another piece of code. There I fill out my first database. however, Id_Cus (primary key) is not transferred to the second table. I used Eager Loading. But there is a feeling that there is an error, because the key is not imported automatically and the second table is empty. I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Yes you are right about where the problem is. You can just add the customer preference as a property of the new customer. I.e.: cust.customerpreference = new customer preference{...};

Comment: What should I indicate in parentheses?
However, I need to work in this class only with Id_Cus, since all the logic is written in another class

Comment: The space in customerpreference was from autocorrect on my phone btw.

Comment: Just initialize its properties between the curly braces. Not sure what the benefit would be of adding an empty customer preference, if that is what you mean - you can just add them when they have been computed.

Comment: I don’t need to initialize all the properties here. I only need to link the two tables. Id_Cus is the primary key between them. however, for some reason I don’t have any data in the customerpreference table. as if the tables are not related. maybe you can tell where I was wrong? when creating the application, database first was used, which means that I imported data and set up navigation properties

Comment: @ NeutralHandle, tried as you said, but I got an error. I attached the code of what I did above, could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: It makes no sense to add an element to an association table with only the linked Id. You have zeros for foreign key values - if you assign a value to a foreign key it has to match something in the associated table. Your code doesn't match my suggestion if you look closely. I think you would be best off finding some tutorials and examples on EF and come back to your code after getting your head around them a bit.

Comment: Okey, I’ll study, but I would like to deal with this example. if I understand you correctly, then the second table should be filled, not just the identifier. I can fill it out, but when filling out I will have to specify Id_Cus in the second table manually. how then to check whether these tables are related?