# relaionship foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have 2 database tables which are connected (the primary key is `Id_Cus`). Below is the function where I add to the customer’s database, when added to the first table, it should automatically (Id_Cus) be imported into the second table. Tell me how to write this function correctly so that the data is transferred?

```
public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
{
        //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities();
        customer cust = new customer();

        cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
        cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
        cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
        cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
        cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(cust.Id_Cus);
        dc.customers.Add(cust);
        dc.SaveChanges();

        cust = (from n in dc.customers
                        where n.Id_Cus == k
                        select n).Include(c => c.customerpreference).ToList().First();
}
```

Perhaps problem is in

```
cust = (from n in dc.customers
                        where n.Id_Cus == k
                        select n).Include(c => c.customerpreference)
           .ToList().First();
```

There are no errors with keys and navigation properties, and cannot be, since I used database-first.

Customer(From EDMX.model)

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class customer
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public customer()
        {
            this.dishesrankings = new HashSet<dishesranking>();
            this.orders = new HashSet<order>();
        }

        public int Id_Cus { get; set; }
        public string FirstName_Cus { get; set; }
        public string LastName_Cus { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNum_Cus { get; set; }
        public string Email_Cus { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<dishesranking> dishesrankings { get; set; }
        public virtual customerpreference customerpreference { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<order> orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomerPrefernce(2nd table)(From EDMX.model)

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class customerpreference
    {
        public int Id_Cus { get; set; }
        public int Id_Res { get; set; }
        public string Name_Dis { get; set; }
        public int Id_Type { get; set; }

        public virtual customer customer { get; set; }
        public virtual order order { get; set; }
        public virtual type_dishes type_dishes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDMX

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MySQLEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MySQLEntities()
            : base("name=MySQLEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<customer> customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<customerpreference> customerpreferences { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<dish> dishes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<dishesranking> dishesrankings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ingridient> ingridients { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<order> orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<restaraunt> restaraunts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<type_dishes> type_dishes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDMX/XML

```
        <EntityType Name="customer">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Cus" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FirstName_Cus" Type="varchar" MaxLength="45" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="LastName_Cus" Type="varchar" MaxLength="75" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="PhoneNum_Cus" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Email_Cus" Type="varchar" MaxLength="200" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="customerpreferences">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Cus" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Res" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Dis" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Type" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="dishes">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Dis" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Dis" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="CookingTime_Dis" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Gram" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Res" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Number_Ord" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="dishesranking">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Cus" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Dis" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Rating" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="ingridients">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Ing" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Ing" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Ing" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Dis" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Dis" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="order">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Number_Ord" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Number_Ord" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Dis" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Cus" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Res" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Order_Time" Type="timestamp" Precision="6" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="restaraunt">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Res" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Res" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Res" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Phone_Res" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Dishes_Res" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Adress_Res" Type="varchar" MaxLength="200" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Email_Res" Type="varchar" MaxLength="200" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="WebSite_Res" Type="varchar" MaxLength="300" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Rating_Res" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="type_dishes">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Type" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Type" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Type" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Dis" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Customer1">
          <End Role="customer" Type="Self.customer" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="dishesranking" Type="Self.dishesranking" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="customer">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="dishesranking">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Dishes1">
          <End Role="dishes" Type="Self.dishes" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="dishesranking" Type="Self.dishesranking" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="dishes">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="dishesranking">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Customer1">
          <End Role="customer" Type="Self.customer" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="customerpreferences" Type="Self.customerpreferences" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="customer">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="customerpreferences">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1">
          <End Role="order" Type="Self.order" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="customerpreferences" Type="Self.customerpreferences" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="order">
              <PropertyRef Name="Number_Ord" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="customerpreferences">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Res" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Type_Dishes1">
          <End Role="type_dishes" Type="Self.type_dishes" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="customerpreferences" Type="Self.customerpreferences" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="type_dishes">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Type" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="customerpreferences">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Type" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Dishes_Order1">
          <End Role="order" Type="Self.order" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="dishes" Type="Self.dishes" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="order">
              <PropertyRef Name="Number_Ord" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="dishes">
              <PropertyRef Name="Number_Ord" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Dishes_Restaraunt1">
          <End Role="restaraunt" Type="Self.restaraunt" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="dishes" Type="Self.dishes" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="restaraunt">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Res" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="dishes">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Res" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Ingridients_Dishes1">
          <End Role="dishes" Type="Self.dishes" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="ingridients" Type="Self.ingridients" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="dishes">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="ingridients">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Order_Customer">
          <End Role="customer" Type="Self.customer" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="order" Type="Self.order" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="customer">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="order">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Order_Restaraunt1">
          <End Role="restaraunt" Type="Self.restaraunt" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="order" Type="Self.order" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="restaraunt">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Res" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="order">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Res" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Type_Dishes_Dishes1">
          <End Role="dishes" Type="Self.dishes" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="type_dishes" Type="Self.type_dishes" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="dishes">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="type_dishes">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <EntityContainer Name="ModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="customer" EntityType="Self.customer" Schema="chik-chak" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="customerpreferences" EntityType="Self.customerpreferences" Schema="chik-chak" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="dishes" EntityType="Self.dishes" Schema="chik-chak" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="dishesranking" EntityType="Self.dishesranking" Schema="chik-chak" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="ingridients" EntityType="Self.ingridients" Schema="chik-chak" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="order" EntityType="Self.order" Schema="chik-chak" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="restaraunt" EntityType="Self.restaraunt" Schema="chik-chak" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="type_dishes" EntityType="Self.type_dishes" Schema="chik-chak" store:Type="Tables" />
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Customer1" Association="Self.fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Customer1">
            <End Role="customer" EntitySet="customer" />
            <End Role="dishesranking" EntitySet="dishesranking" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Dishes1" Association="Self.fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Dishes1">
            <End Role="dishes" EntitySet="dishes" />
            <End Role="dishesranking" EntitySet="dishesranking" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Customer1" Association="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Customer1">
            <End Role="customer" EntitySet="customer" />
            <End Role="customerpreferences" EntitySet="customerpreferences" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1" Association="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1">
            <End Role="order" EntitySet="order" />
            <End Role="customerpreferences" EntitySet="customerpreferences" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Type_Dishes1" Association="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Type_Dishes1">
            <End Role="type_dishes" EntitySet="type_dishes" />
            <End Role="customerpreferences" EntitySet="customerpreferences" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Dishes_Order1" Association="Self.fk_Dishes_Order1">
            <End Role="order" EntitySet="order" />
            <End Role="dishes" EntitySet="dishes" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Dishes_Restaraunt1" Association="Self.fk_Dishes_Restaraunt1">
            <End Role="restaraunt" EntitySet="restaraunt" />
            <End Role="dishes" EntitySet="dishes" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Ingridients_Dishes1" Association="Self.fk_Ingridients_Dishes1">
            <End Role="dishes" EntitySet="dishes" />
            <End Role="ingridients" EntitySet="ingridients" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Order_Customer" Association="Self.fk_Order_Customer">
            <End Role="customer" EntitySet="customer" />
            <End Role="order" EntitySet="order" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Order_Restaraunt1" Association="Self.fk_Order_Restaraunt1">
            <End Role="restaraunt" EntitySet="restaraunt" />
            <End Role="order" EntitySet="order" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Type_Dishes_Dishes1" Association="Self.fk_Type_Dishes_Dishes1">
            <End Role="dishes" EntitySet="dishes" />
            <End Role="type_dishes" EntitySet="type_dishes" />
          </AssociationSet>
        </EntityContainer>
      </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="Model" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <EntityType Name="customer">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Cus" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FirstName_Cus" Type="String" MaxLength="45" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="LastName_Cus" Type="String" MaxLength="75" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="PhoneNum_Cus" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Email_Cus" Type="String" MaxLength="200" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="dishesrankings" Relationship="Self.fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Customer1" FromRole="customer" ToRole="dishesranking" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="customerpreference" Relationship="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Customer1" FromRole="customer" ToRole="customerpreferences" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="orders" Relationship="Self.fk_Order_Customer" FromRole="customer" ToRole="order" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="customerpreference">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Cus" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Res" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Dis" Type="String" MaxLength="100" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Type" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="customer" Relationship="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Customer1" FromRole="customerpreferences" ToRole="customer" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="order" Relationship="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1" FromRole="customerpreferences" ToRole="order" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="type_dishes" Relationship="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Type_Dishes1" FromRole="customerpreferences" ToRole="type_dishes" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="dish">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Dis" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Dis" Type="String" MaxLength="100" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="CookingTime_Dis" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Gram" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Res" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Number_Ord" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="dishesrankings" Relationship="Self.fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Dishes1" FromRole="dishes" ToRole="dishesranking" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="order" Relationship="Self.fk_Dishes_Order1" FromRole="dishes" ToRole="order" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="restaraunt" Relationship="Self.fk_Dishes_Restaraunt1" FromRole="dishes" ToRole="restaraunt" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="ingridients" Relationship="Self.fk_Ingridients_Dishes1" FromRole="dishes" ToRole="ingridients" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="type_dishes" Relationship="Self.fk_Type_Dishes_Dishes1" FromRole="dishes" ToRole="type_dishes" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="dishesranking">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Dis" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Cus" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Dis" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Rating" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="customer" Relationship="Self.fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Customer1" FromRole="dishesranking" ToRole="customer" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="dish" Relationship="Self.fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Dishes1" FromRole="dishesranking" ToRole="dishes" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="ingridient">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id_Ing" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id_Ing" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Ing" Type="String" MaxLength="100" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name_Dis" Type="String" MaxLength="100" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Id_Dis" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="dish" Relationship="Self.fk_Ingridients_Dishes1" FromRole="ingridients" ToRole="dishes" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="order">
          <Key>

        </EntityType>
          <NavigationProperty Name="orders" Relationship="Self.fk_Order_Restaraunt1" FromRole="restaraunt" ToRole="order" />
        Relationship="Self.fk_Type_Dishes_Dishes1" FromRole="type_dishes" ToRole="dishes" />
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Customer1">
          <End Role="customer" Type="Self.customer" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="dishesranking" Type="Self.dishesranking" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="customer">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="dishesranking">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Customer1">
          <End Role="customer" Type="Self.customer" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="customerpreferences" Type="Self.customerpreference" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="customer">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="customerpreferences">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Order_Customer">
          <End Role="customer" Type="Self.customer" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="order" Type="Self.order" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="customer">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="order">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Cus" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1">
          <End Role="order" Type="Self.order" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="customerpreferences" Type="Self.customerpreference" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="order">
              <PropertyRef Name="Number_Ord" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="customerpreferences">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Res" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
            <Dependent Role="customerpreferences">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id_Type" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="fk_Dishes_Restaraunt1">
          Association="Self.fk_Customer_has_Dishes_Customer1">
            <End Role="customer" EntitySet="customers" />
            <End Role="dishesranking" EntitySet="dishesrankings" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Customer1" Association="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Customer1">
            <End Role="customer" EntitySet="customers" />
            <End Role="customerpreferences" EntitySet="customerpreferences" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_Order_Customer" Association="Self.fk_Order_Customer">
            <End Role="customer" EntitySet="customers" />
            <End Role="order" EntitySet="orders" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1" Association="Self.fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1">
            <End Role="order" EntitySet="orders" />
            <End Role="customerpreferences" EntitySet="customerpreferences" />
          </AssociationSet>
          </AssociationSet>
          </AssociationSet>
        </EntityContainer>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="ModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="MySQLEntities">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="customers">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Model.customer">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="customer">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id_Cus" ColumnName="Id_Cus" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FirstName_Cus" ColumnName="FirstName_Cus" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="LastName_Cus" ColumnName="LastName_Cus" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="PhoneNum_Cus" ColumnName="PhoneNum_Cus" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Email_Cus" ColumnName="Email_Cus" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="customerpreferences">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Model.customerpreference">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="customerpreferences">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id_Cus" ColumnName="Id_Cus" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id_Res" ColumnName="Id_Res" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Name_Dis" ColumnName="Name_Dis" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id_Type" ColumnName="Id_Type" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtrsO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR5Rc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIHkE.png)

Comment: Apart from some bad naming convention, I don't quite see what the problem is in this code. Can you describe what part of your code is not behaving the way you want? What is happening when you run this code?

Comment: This function creates a customer in the first table. The first and second table are connected by the primary key (Id_Cus), so when I create the first table Id_Cus should be automatically imported into the second table (for this I used eager loading with Include method). When this function is executed, no errors occur and everything is created correctly in the first table, however (Id_Cus) is not imported into the second table (it is completely empty). I think I am using Eager Loading incorrectly.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Use data to show the first place it doesn't do what you expect when run. Explain why you expected something else. (Basic debugging.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship (database first) in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187981/relationship-database-first-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Yes, it's my question

Answer (score 0):

Now I think we have all the information to outline the issues you are having. The bottom line is that foreign key (FK) constraints work differently than the way I think you understand them. FK constraints are merely "rules" that the data in your database need to comply with. FK constraints **do not** introduce any automation, such as adding a row to `Table2` just because you inserted something in `Table1`. This is something **you need to do explicitly**.

#### To address your issue:

The relationship between your tables are as follows (based on the EDMX file contents you posted):

```
TableA      |  Cardinality  | TableB
------------------------------------------------
customer    |  1 <--> 0..*  | dishesranking
dishes      |  1 <--> 0..*  | dishesranking
customer    |  1 <--> 0..1  | customerpreferences
order       |  1 <--> 0..*  | customerpreferences
type_dishes |  1 <--> 0..*  | customerpreferences
order       |  1 <--> 0..*  | dishes
restaraunt  |  1 <--> 0..*  | dishes
dishes      |  1 <--> 0..*  | ingridients
customer    |  1 <--> 0..*  | order
restaraunt  |  1 <--> 0..*  | order
dishes      |  1 <--> 0..*  | type_dishes
```

Currently you can insert data into the `customer` table without issues and you have shown data appears in the database in this table such as in your first image. No problems here. This is because, as the above table shows, a row in the `customer` table does not require any data in other tables (the right side of the cardinality allows "0" for all other tables).

**However**, if you want to insert something into `customerpreferences` then you **need to have** something in `customer`, `order` and `type_dishes` as well. E.g. `order |  1 <--> 0..*  | customerpreferences` means that for every `customerpreferences` there **has to be an** `order`.

All of the above is the definition of a FK constraint. It's just rules - no automation is involved.

Now... your expectation is that because you insert something into `customer` you expect something to be inserted into `customerpreference` as well. This is not how a FK constraint works. You need to insert something manually into `customerpreference`. However, because `customerpreference` has other FK constraints, as you can see from the cardinalities above, you also need to insert something in `order` and `type_dishes` before you can insert anything into `customerpreference`. As my table shows this pattern continues: in order to insert anything into `order` you need to have something in `customer` and `restaraunt`... and so on.

#### How to insert data

I'm not gonna give you a complete code example because you have too many FK constraints between your tables for me to make a small example. However, in order to insert data in your database you need to do it in this order:

1. Insert `restaraunt` (`rest1`)
2. Insert `customer` (`cust1`)
3. Insert `order` (`ord1`), where:

   - `ord1.Id_Cus = cust1.Id_Cus`
   - `ord1.Id_Res = rest1.Id_Res`
4. Insert `dishes` (`dish1`), where:

   - `dish1.Number_Ord = ord1.Number_Ord`
   - `dish1.Id_Res = rest1.Id_Res`
5. Insert `type_dishes` (`typDish1`), where:

   - `typDish1.Id_Dis = dish1.Id_Dis`
6. Insert `customerpreferences` (`custPref1`), where:

   - `custPref1.Id_Cus = cust1.Id_Cus`
   - `custPref1.Number_Ord = ord1.Number_Ord`
   - `custPref1.Id_Type = typDish1.Id_Type`

Before you have completed step 1-5 it's not gonna be possible to insert anything into `customerpreferences`, because the FK constraints on `customerpreferences` requires that something already exists in `customer`, `dishes` and `type_dishes` (see the cardinality table). If you do try to insert anything in `customerpreferences` before step 6, you will see the error (or similar) you described in the comments:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (chik-chak. Custompreferences, CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1` FOREIGN KEY (Id_Res) REFERENCES` order` (Number_Ord))
```

This specific error tells you, that you **cannot** insert anything into `customerpreference` without setting `customerpreference.Number_Ord` to an ID mathing an element in the `order` table.

#### Summary

As you can see from above, you have a quite complicated setup of FK constraints in your database and I would **highly suggest** that you read and understand how foreign key constraints work before you continue any further with your project. This also means that you should understand how you can insert data through simple SQL commands in the database, before you work with this in Entity Framework (EF). It will give you a much better understanding which is difficult to get when working with EF alone, because EF hides some of these details - that's what makes EF brilliant but at the same time can make it difficult to understand relational databases if you are new to it.

#### Old answer:

````
### My understanding of your question:

> This function creates a customer in the first table. The first and second table are connected by the primary key (Id_Cus), so when I create the first table Id_Cus should be automatically imported into the second table (for this I used eager loading with Include method). When this function is executed, no errors occur and everything is created correctly in the first table, however (Id_Cus) is not imported into the second table (it is completely empty).

If I understand correctly from your comment, you have two tables defined somewhat like this:

**EDIT:** you have added your own database models in your question so I've removed my examples here.

What you're trying to do is to read an entity from the `customer` table and include that customer's preferences from the `customerpreferences` table, so you can see it in the navigation property `c.customerpreference` - correct me if I'm wrong.

---

In your example, you are never adding/saving anything to the `customerpreference` table. What you need is to create a `customerpreferences` along with you `customer`. This could be done in two ways to ensure there's a relationship between the two tables

### Example 1

-```
public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
{
    customer cust = new customer()
    {
        Id_Cus = customerDataContract.Id_Cus,
        FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus,
        LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus,
        PhoneNum_Cus = customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus,
        Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus,

        customerpreference = new customerpreference()
        {
            Id_Cus = customerDataContract.Id_Cus
            Id_Res = x, // some value
            Name_Dis = y, // some value
            Id_Type = z // some value
        }
    };

    // EF knows that cust.customerpreference should be saved in
    // the customerpreferences table
    dc.customers.Add(cust);
    dc.SaveChanges();

    customer custFromDb =
        (from n in dc.customers
         where n.Id_Cus == k
         select n)
        .Include(c => c.customerpreference)
        .First();
    // custFromDb.customerpreference should no longer be null
}
-```

### Example 2

-```
public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
{
    customer cust = new customer()
    {
        Id_Cus = customerDataContract.Id_Cus,
        FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus,
        LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus,
        PhoneNum_Cus = customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus,
        Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus
    };

    dc.customers.Add(cust);

    customerpreference custPref = new customerpreference()
    {
        Id_Cus = customerDataContract.Id_Cus
        Id_Res = x, // some value
        Name_Dis = y, // some value
        Id_Type = z // some value
    };

    dc.customerpreferences.Add(custPref);

    // Now the entities are saved separately in each table
    dc.SaveChanges();

    customer custFromDb =
        (from n in dc.customers
         where n.Id_Cus == k
         select n)
        .Include(c => c.customerpreference)
        .First();
    // custFromDb.customerpreference should no longer be null
}
-```
````

Comment: You got it right. I acted according to your recommendations, but again the data was not added to the second table.
So, maybe I missed something, let's try again. I have 2 tables where there are keys and navigation properties (I added code to these properties). Both tables are connected by a primary key (Id_Cus). I want that when filling in the data in the first table (data from the Id_Cus column) fill the same column but in the second table.

Comment: What should I indicate in parentheses?
However, I need to work in this class only with Id_Cus, since all the logic is written in another class (cust.customerpreference = new CustomerPreference(...);)

Comment: Why do you need `customerpreference.Id_Cus` to be set? If you set `cust.customerpreference = new customerpreference()` then you should get a row in the `customerpreferences` table. I suggest you [read this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) to understand the use of navigation properties and foreign key IDs. If you need `customerpreference.Id_Cus` to be set you should call it `customerId` instead

Comment: Thanks for the article, I already came across it today. It is not a question of setting a value in customerpreference. And to use the primary key and connect the two tables. primary key is Id_Cus. And one more thing, maybe there are incorrectly indicated navigation properties. But I used the Database First approach, which means that all keys and properties were imported automatically by the Entity Framework. as far as I learned during import, errors rarely occur and it seems to me that now they are not there.

Comment: Once again, I perfectly dealt with the article that you sent me, but all keys and properties are set automatically using EF.
so I don’t understand where there might be a mistake

Comment: Ah, I forgot the DB-first detail among all the other things. The thing is, in your code right now, you are not creating a `new customerpreference()` anywhere, so nothing is going in that table - this doesn't happen automatically because EF has no idea about what it should put in that table. You need to create a `new customerpreference()`, fill out it's properties  and save it to the database. I've updated my answer with examples. If this doesn't work, do you have an `.edmx` file that shows how your database is structured?

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I tried both options, unfortunately this did not help. In the first option, an error occurs when creating "customerpreference = new customerpreference" and in the second there are no errors at the compilation stage, but when I start adding data, an exception appears in the place where I save the database: dc.SaveChanges () "System.Data.Entity. Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See' EntityValidationErrors 'property for more details.'
"

Comment: Of course I have a .edmx file (3rd picture)
Above, I will attach a screenshot with all the attachments that are there. What do you need?

Comment: I don’t know if you understood me correctly, so I’ll try to explain again. I have 2 tables that have a one-to-many relationship, tables connected with the primary key "Id_Cus", however when I fill out the first table, the key data (Namely Id_Cus) does not move to the second table. i.e. as if the tables are not connected.

Comment: as I understand the work of this - there are 2 tables in one, I enter data for Customer, since there is Id_Cus in 1 table and Id_Cus in 2 table, then I want the data from the first table (namely, only the Id_Cus import) of this column to be imported into the second table (i.e., in the second table, only the Id_Cus field should be filled). I understand correctly that this is a regular key?

Comment: 1: Which error are you getting? Did you replace `x`, `y`, `z` with something? (or removed them?) 2: Can you share the contents of the `.edmx`? I can't see from the image how the tables and their relations are configured. 3: As the `DbEntityValidationException` says, the `EntityValidationErrors` property describes the actual error, what does that say? 4: I do think I understand your problem, but the thing is just because you have an N to N relationship between two tables it doesn't mean anything will be imported automatically from one to the other. You need to have the code do that.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what a [foreign key constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) is. This constraint simply means, that if you specify a value in the foreign key column in the child table, then a row in the other (parent) table HAS to exist with that value (primary key). Inserting data into the tables is always something you have to do explicitly - it doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: Yes, I can share the contents of the edmx file. But if you want to check the table settings, then I originally attached them (from the edmx file). Yes, I replaced the variables x, y, z with random values ​​not equal to zero, based on the data types that were required for each field.
Below I will describe in detail the errors that occur.

Comment: Both methods have the same error, at the compilation stage everything works fine. Then, when I try to create a table, an error occurs on the line (dc.SaveChanges ();) with an exception (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.' / /
MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`chik-chak`. Custompreferences`, CONSTRAINT` fk_CustomerPreferences_Order1` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Res`) REFERENCES` order` (`Number_Ord`)))

Comment: As I understand it, in this case I just need to add the correct Number_Ord from the order table to Id_Res

Comment: Correct, this seems to be a problem between the `order` table and `customerpreferences` table. I would **really** advice you to learn and understand how foreign key constraints work in SQL before you try to make it work in Entity Framework. Try inserting data directly in the database and understand that **before** trying to make Entity Framework work. If you need more help (after understanding foreign key constraints) **please post the contents of the EDMX file** - not an image. It's not possible for me to predict what you're missing without knowing the structure of your data.

Comment: Did I understand correctly. for EF to work correctly, for example, pass Id_Cus to another table, other tables and relationships must be implemented, because Do they all refer to each other?
Maybe this is exactly the problem now? I have only the Customer table populated, then I try to transfer Id_Cus to another table. I do as in your example and then an error appears that when I fill out some field in customerpreference it passes the data further to the next table and that one is empty.
I added an edmx model for these two tables

Comment: An `.edmx` file is an XML file such as [this one](https://github.com/entityframeworktutorial/EF6-DBFirst-Demo/blob/master/EF6DBFirstDemo/School.edmx). What you have posted is the code-classes generated from the EDMX file and not the EDMX file itself. So I can't see how the relationship between the tables are actually configured. I need to see the XML itself. It seems to me you are still misunderstanding foreign key constraints. No data is automatically "transferred" to other tables. You need to explicitly do this yourself.

Comment: I'm added XML file, let me know if you will find problem. 
I will study it, thanks for help

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. I made a completely new answer to hopefully explain it so that you can implement it as needed. The important note is that when you insert something in `customer`, nothing is going to be inserted/transferred to `customerpreferences` unless you do that explicitly

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Yes, yesterday I was trying to find out exactly from you whether it is possible to fill out one table without filling out the others. Well now I have an understanding and I can begin to study literature. Of course, this is not quite the right approach, that I did not immediately study it in detail, but on the site where I taught it simply did not exist, because the examples were usually with 1-2 tables. In any case, much has now become clear to me. Thanks again for all your answers :)

Comment: a small question to top it off, maybe you could suggest some useful book? Yesterday I searched for your recommendations and as a rule not many books consider all three approaches (DB first, code and model first), but I would like to understand everything. Thank you again for all your answers !!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had my hands on any specific resources so I sadly don't have much to recommend. However, I do remember using Khan Academy's website way back to get introduced to SQL. They'll give you some free online step-by-step exercises to understand basics of SQL. Maybe some of it is useful to you.